# MongoMapper can't save a document with simple example

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I'll admit I'm still new to Ruby and now mongoDB so i'm guessing i'm doing something dumb.
For a test I have this code called tester.rb:

```
require 'Mongo_Mapper'
MongoMapper.database = "myTestDB"

class Person
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :first_name, String
  key :last_name, String
end
person = Person.new(:first_name => "FirstNameHere", :last_name => "LastNameHere")
person.save
```

I'll run that code with no errors.
I jump over to mongoDB....my myTestDB has been created, yeah!  But if i do "db.myTestDB.find()" I see nothing....
I tried "Person.create()" as well, nada...nothing stored.

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong....
ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you're calling your find() method wrong in your mongodb command line.

You can see what collections are in your db by running:

```
show collections
```

You should see something like:

```
system.indexes
people
```

If you see the "people" collection, you can then run:

```
db.people.find()
```

to see all of the records that are in that collection.

Hope this helps!